# How do I get the achievement "A new you." in the Elder Scrolls 5 Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements, skyrim-dawnguard

When I was in the achievements looking for Skyrim's Dawnguard DLC achievements, I noticed there is an achievement called, "A new you" and the description is to change your face. It appears on the second bar in the picture below.

[image: Achievement list]

In the beginning of the game you get to make your own face, and now I heard you can change your face. So how do I change my face?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=a+new+you+skyrim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to go to the ragged flagon in Riften and talk to Galathil and pay her 1,000 gold. You don't even have to actually to change anything as it pops right away. [Source](http://www.xboxachievements.com/game/elder-scrolls-v/achievement/68250-A-New-You.html)

Comment: You can also just quicksave and reload so as not to lose money.